# OMP for loop with no initialization

Tags: c++, iterator, openmp

I am trying to run a code snippet using openmp, but it gives compile error as there is no initialization in the `for` loop. The iterator `class` is defined [here](https://github.com/bcgsc/ntHash/blob/master/ntHashIterator.hpp). I am not able to figure out how can I initialize inside the `for` loop.

I am not an expert in C++, so I would appreciate any help.

```
ntHashIterator itr(seq, h, k);
#pragma omp parallel for  
for(; itr != itr.end(); ++itr){ 
   std::cout << (*itr)[0] << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Try `for (ntHashIterator itr = ntHashIterator(seq, h, k); itr != itr.end(); ++itr)`

Comment: Thanks @acraig5075 !! I tried that, but it was giving `invalid controlling predicate` error. I think the answer below explains that.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP requires loops to be in so-called *canonical loop form*. Moreover, it can works with iterators, but they have to be of a *random-access iterator* type. Which doesn't seem to be your case, since your `nHashIterator` does not support `+` and `+=` operators. See the OpenMP specifications for more details.

Anyway, it's hard to tell more, since you are not providing enough details such as a compiler and OpenMP version which it supports.

Comment: That the *canonical loop form* also requires `it < end()` as loop condition even if `it` is a random access iterator.

Comment: Thanks Daniel !! I got the idea now. I am using `gcc (GCC) 7.3.0`.